# How can I speed up deep learning on a non-NVIDIA setup?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, theano, caffe, torch

Since I only have an AMD A10-7850 APU, and do not have the funds to spend on a $800-$1200 NVIDIA graphics card, I am trying to make due with the resources I have in order to speed up deep learning via tensorflow/keras.

Initially, I used a pre-compiled version of Tensorflow. InceptionV3 would take about 1000-1200 seconds to compute 1 epoch. It has been painfully slow.

To speed up calculations, I first self-compiled Tensorflow with optimizers (using AVX, and SSE4 instructions). This lead to a roughly 40% decrease in computation times. The same computations performed above now only take about 600 seconds to compute. It's almost bearable - kind of like you can watch paint dry.

I am looking for ways to further decrease computation times. I only have an integrated AMD graphics card that is part of the APU. (How) (C/c)an I make use of this resource to speed up computation even more?

More generally, let's say there are other people with similar monetary restrictions and Intel setups. How can anyone WITHOUT discrete NVIDIA cards make use of their integrated graphics chips or otherwise non-NVIDIA setup to achieve faster than CPU-only performance? Is that possible? Why/Why not? What needs to be done to achieve this goal? Or will this be possible in the near future (2-6 months)? How?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After researching this topic for a few months, I can see 3.5 possible paths forward:

1.) Tensorflow + OpenCl as mentioned in the comments above:

There seems to be some movement going on this field. Over at Codeplay, Lukasz Iwanski just posted a comprehensive answer on how to get tensorflow to run with opencl here (I will only provide a link as stated above because the information might change there): https://www.codeplay.com/portal/03-30-17-setting-up-tensorflow-with-opencl-using-sycl

The potential to use integrated graphics is alluring. It's also worth exploring the use of this combination with APUs. But I am not sure how well this will work since OpenCl support is still early in development, and hardware support is very limited. Furthermore, OpenCl is not the same as a handcrafted library of optimized code. (UPDATE 2017-04-24: I have gotten the code to compile after running into some issues [here](https://github.com/benoitsteiner/tensorflow-opencl/issues/65)!) Unfortunately, the hoped for speed improvements **ON MY SETUP (iGPU)** did not materialize.

**CIFAR 10 Dataset:**

1. Tensorflow (via pip ak unoptimized):  1700sec/epoch at 390% CPU
   utilization.
2. Tensorflow (SSE4, AVX): 1100sec/epoch at 390% CPU
   utilization.
3. Tensorflow (opencl + iGPU): 5800sec/epoch at 150% CPU
   and 100% GPU utilization.

Your mileage may vary significantly. So I am wondering what are other people getting relatively speaking (unoptimized vs optimized vs opencl) on your setups?

What should be noted: opencl implementation means that all the heavy computation should be done on the GPU. (Updated on 2017/4/29) But in reality this is not the case yet because some functions have not been implemented yet. This leads to [unnecessary copying back and forth of data between CPU and GPU ram](https://github.com/lukeiwanski/tensorflow/issues/7). Again, [imminent changes](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/9117) should improve the situation. And furthermore, for those interested in helping out and those wanting to speed things up, we can do something that will have a measurable impact on the performance of tensorflow with opencl.

But as it stands for now: 1 iGPU << 4 CPUS with SSE+AVX. Perhaps beefier GPUs with larger RAM and/or opencl 2.0 implementation could have made a larger difference.

At this point, I should add that similar efforts have been going on with at least Caffe and/or Theano + OpenCl. The limiting step in all cases appears to be the manual porting of CUDA/cuDNN functionality to the openCl paradigm.

Update 2023-06-29: Please refer to section 5 and onwards below for a state-of-the-art update. These sections are only kept because the concept is still relevant, but performance numbers are no longer relevant.

2.) RocM + MIOpen

[RocM](https://github.com/RadeonOpenCompute/ROCm) stands for Radeon Open Compute and seems to be a hodgepodge of initiatives that is/will make deep-learning possible on non-NVIDIA (mostly Radeon devices). It includes 3 major components:

- HIP: A tool that converts CUDA code to code that can be consumed by AMD GPUs.
- ROCk: a 64-bit linux kernel driver for AMD CPU+GPU devices.
- HCC: A C/C++ compiler that compiles code into code for a heterogeneous system architecture environment (HSA).

Apparently, RocM is designed to play to AMDs strenghts of having both CPU and GPU technology. Their approach to speeding up deep-learning make use of both components. As an APU owner, I am particularly interested in this possibility. But as a cautionary note: Kaveri APUs have limited support (only integrated graphcs is supported). Future APUs have not been released yet. And it appears, there is still a lot of work that is being done here to bring this project to a mature state. A lot of work will hopefully make this approach viable within a year given that AMD has announced their Radeon Instinct cards will be released this year (2017).

The problem here for me is that that RocM is providing tools for building deep learning libraries. They do not themselves represent deep learning libraries. As a data scientist who is not focused on tools development, I just want something that works. and am not necessarily interested in building what I want to then do the learning. There are not enough hours in the day to do both well at the company I am at.

Update 2023-06-29: Please refer to section 5 and onwards below for a state-of-the-art update. These sections are only kept because the concept is still relevant, but performance numbers are no longer relevant.

NVIDIA has of course CUDA and cuDNN which are libaries of hand-crafted assembler code optimized for NVIDIA GPUs. All major deep learning frameworks build on top of these proprietary libraries. AMD currently does not have anything like that at all.

I am uncertain how successfully AMD will get to where NVIDIA is in this regard. But there is some light being shone on what AMDs intentions are in an article posted by Carlos Perez on 4/3/2017 [here](http://instinct.radeon.com/en-us/the-potential-disruptiveness-of-amds-open-source-deep-learning-strategy/). A recent [lecture at Stanford](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2LksDHe43rU) also talks in general terms about Ryzen, Vega and deep learning fit together. In essence, the article states that MIOpen will represent this hand-crafted library of optimized deep learning functions for AMD devices. This library is set to be released in H1 of 2017. I am uncertain how soon these libraries would be incorporated into the major deep learning frameworks and what the scope of functional implementation will be then at this time.

But apparently, [AMD has already worked with the developers of Caffe to "hippify" the code basis](https://www.slideshare.net/insideHPC/hip-and-caffe-porting-and-profiling-with-amds-rocm). Basically, CUDA code is converted automatically to C code via HIP. The automation takes care of the vast majority of the code basis, leaving only less than 0.5% of code had to be changed and required manual attention. Compare that to the manual translation into openCl code, and one starts getting the feeling that this approach might be more sustainable. What I am not clear about is where the lower-level assembler language optimization come in.

(Update 2017-05-19) But with the imminent release of AMD Vega cards (the professional Frontier Edition card not for consumers will be first), there are hints that [major deep learning frameworks **will** be supported through the MIOpen framework](https://www.reddit.com/r/Amd/comments/6bklro/we_are_radeon_technologies_group_at_amd_and_were/dhqoalj/). A [Forbes article](https://www.forbes.com/sites/moorinsights/2017/05/16/amd-targets-machine-learning-with-new-radeon-vega-frontier-optimized-software/#b6a9a1b3e5bb) released today shows the progress MiOpen has taken over just the last couple of months in terms of performance: it appears significant.
(Update 2017-08-25) MiOpen has officially been released. We are no longer talking in hypotheticals here. Now we just need to try out how well this framework works.

3.) Neon

[Neon](https://github.com/NervanaSystems/neon) is Nervana's (now acquired by Intel) open-source deep-learning framework. The reason I mention this framework is that it seems to be fairly straightforward to use. The syntax is about as easy and intuitive as Keras. More importantly though, this framework has achieved speeds up to 2x faster than Tensorflow on [some benchmarks](https://github.com/soumith/convnet-benchmarks) due to some hand-crafted assembler language optimization for those computations. Potentially, cutting computation times from 500 secs/epoch down to 300 secs/epoch is nothing to sneeze at. 300 secs = 5 minutes. So one could get 15 epochs in in an hour. and about 50 epochs in about 3.5 hours! But ideally, I want to do these kinds of calculations in under an hour. To get to those levels, I need to use a GPU, and at this point, only NVIDIA offers full support in this regard: Neon also uses CUDA and cuDNN when a GPU is available (and of course, it has to be an NVIDIA GPU). If you have access other Intel hardware this is of course a valid way to pursue. Afterall, Neon was developed out of a motivation to get things to work optimally also on non-NVIDIA setups (like Nervana's custom CPUs, and now Intel FPGAs or Xeon Phis).

3.5.) Intel Movidius

Update 2017-08-25: I came across [this article](https://newsroom.intel.com/news/intel-democratizes-deep-learning-application-development-launch-movidius-neural-compute-stick/). Intel has released a USB3.0-stick-based "deep learning" accelerator. Apparently, it works with Cafe and allows the user perform common Cafe-based fine-tuning of networks and inference. This is important stressing: If you want to train your own network from scratch, the wording is very ambiguous here. I will therefore assume, that apart from fine-tuning a network, training itself should still be done on something with more parallel compute. The real kicker though is this: When I checked for the pricing this stick costs a mere $79. That's nothing compared to the cost of your average NVIDIA 1070-80(ti) card. If you merely want to tackle some vision problems using common network topologies already available for some related tasks, you can use this stick to fine tune it to your own use, then compile the code and put it into this stick to do inference quickly. Many use cases can be covered with this stick, and for again $79 it could be worth it. This being Intel, they are proposing to go all out on Intel. Their model is to use the cloud (i.e. Nervana Cloud) for training. Then, use this chip for prototype inference or inference where energy consumption matters. Whether this is the right approach or not is left for the reader to answer.

Update 2023-06-29:

At this time, it looks like major ML libraries now support AMD to some degree.

4.) TensorFlow-DirectML

In revisiting this topic in 2023, it appears that a lot of progress has been made in this field. With TensorFlow-DirectML, it is possible to work in Tensforflow with AMD graphics cards.

Source: https://community.amd.com/t5/radeon-pro-graphics/amd-gpus-support-gpu-accelerated-machine-learning-with-release/ba-p/488595

5.) PyTorch 2.0

It appears that Pytorch 2.0 also now supports training and inference on AMD GPUs now. Not all GPUs are supported though. So the user must double check prior to purchase whether a given GPU is supported.

Source: https://pytorch.org/blog/experience-power-pytorch-2.0/

Given that both Pytorch and Tensorflow have some form of AMD GPU support, in 2023, it appears that training and inference on an AMD GPU is finally now possible.

There are some caveats though: In addition to not supporting all GPUs (e.g.: older iGPU), performances between different GPUs of the same tier is unknown. When I find benchmarks that compare performances for training and inference for AMD GPUs, I will list them here.

Additionally, even if libraries or branches of libraries support ML on AMD GPUs, it appears these libraries are updated less frequently because the community is smaller. From this perspective, there is still a gap in support.

A very insightful article by Tim Dettmers, has [a section on ML training with AMD GPUs](https://timdettmers.com/2023/01/30/which-gpu-for-deep-learning/#Will_AMD_GPUs_ROCm_ever_catch_up_with_NVIDIA_GPUs_CUDA). The short summary of it is: Until AMD introduces tensor cores, which significantly speed ML training and inference, into their GPUs which could happen in the next iteration, and has developed a larger community around its use, NVIDIA will still have an edge in these category for at least the next 1-2 years.

At this time, it still looks like deep learning without NVIDIA is still slightly more difficult to realize although major barriers have been removed, and significant progress has been made.

Comment: Can you point me to the instructions on how to run the benchmark you refer to with _CIFAR 10 Dataset_ please?

Comment: Okay, I played around with AMD and ROCm. AMD cannot be used with latest Tensorflow, only with version 1.0.1 from 2017. Bought an NVidia card instead, now all GPU accelerated software just works.

Comment: I can confirm your assumptions regarding Intel Movidius. You'll need to do your training elsewhere and then import your trained model into OpenVino to do the inferencing on Movidius. The current version can import a trained model from Caffe, TensorFlow, MXNet, Kaldi, and ONNX. If you go this route, you will need to keep OpenVino's limitations in mind when defining your model. It doesn't support every topology or operation.

Answer (score 2):

If your platform supports opencl you can look at using it with tensorflow. There is some experimental support for it on Linux at [this github repository](https://github.com/benoitsteiner/tensorflow-opencl). Some preliminary instructions are at [the documentation section of of this github repository](https://github.com/benoitsteiner/tensorflow-opencl/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/get_started/os_setup.md#optional-install-opencl-experimental-linux-only).

Comment: There's some high level information about the OpenCL implementation status here as well in case that also helps. But Benoit's branch linked is the right place to go https://www.codeplay.com/portal/02-14-17-bringing-the-acceleration-of-opencl-to-tensorflow-with-sycl